# Google map integration

Tags: google-maps

Drupal 7 google map integration.

I need a google map on my drupal 7 website.I have a content type for properties.In this type there are latitude and longitude fields available.How can we mark all the properties in  google map by using this lat and lng fields? Also i want to show an info window for each points with the image and title of each nodes in the content type.

please suggest me a solution.